# Creating custom dialog results in extra space across expected dialog area

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am creating a custom alert dialog, having custom background color.
I have defined a theme for that which looks as below,

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
</style>
```

The code to make use of this theme looks like below,

```
public class FireDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

String[] stringArray = { "Style1", "Sytle2", "Style3" };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialog));

    builder.setTitle("Custom Style");
    builder.setItems(stringArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked: "+which, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
    }
}
```

The custom dialog thus created is not as expected and looks below,

[image: Custom Dialog]

Red lines show extra space/unexpected space and black strips(at two ends of title) which I want to avoid. Any help to achieve this? I am not sure if I am missing some attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this style, actually black color is default color for dialog:

```
 <style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I want custom color with the dialog, this will give me default theme.